# How to use Javascript Promise based functions correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm new so apologies for the lack of information.

I have Promise based function which returns an object. I then pass a key value from that property in order to create another object.

I am getting an issue, where my new object which I am creating, returns undefined. Im thinking this is due to the async nature of JS?

Please see below..

```
  post(postObject).then((result) => {
    console.log(result); // token found in returned object. See OBJ1 below
    const cookie = {
      name: 'jwtToken',
      value: result.token,
      path: '/',
      domain: '.' + APP_HOST,
      secure: false
    };
    console.log(cookie); // result.token not returned. Getting undefined
    page.addCookie(cookie);
  });
```

cookie.value is coming back as undefined

I need to be able to pass the result.token as the cookie value.

When I console log result, I can see the token key value generated.

Below is what gets returned from 'result'. I am trying to get hold of 'token' so I am doing result.token. But this is giving me 'undefined' all the time.

OBJ1:

```
{"token":"skjdhjkshds.sdhskjdhkshdjs.shdkjshdkjsh","isCartMerged":false}
```

Comment: Where do you console log the `cookie `?  If you console log it outside this function you could get empty string.

Comment: Added console logs in my question to show whats happening.

Comment: is OBJ1 coming back as a string?  Can you try JSON.parse() on it? [see](https://jsfiddle.net/zn7c70oe/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems likely that your `result` is a JSON string and you need to parse it in order to get at the individual properties as an object.  You can verify this for sure by inserting `console.log(typeof result)` at the start of your `.then()` handler to see if it is a string or an object.

```
  post(postObject).then((result) => {
    console.log(typeof result);       // probably shows "string"
    console.log(result);
    var parsedResult = JSON.parse(result);
    console.log(parsedResult);
    const cookie = {
      name: 'jwtToken',
      value: parsedResult.token,
      path: '/',
      domain: '.' + APP_HOST,
      secure: false
    };
    console.log(cookie);
    page.addCookie(cookie);
  });
```